# Text not aligned horizontally in li

Tags: html, css

Hi I am using below code and my text is not getting aligned horizontally within Li.
HTML code:

```
        <body>
<div id="image_header">
<img src="header.jpg" width="500" height="54" />
</div>
<div id="header">
<div id="left_panel">
<h2 id="heading" align="cente">Welcome to the <br />
Help Center</h2>

 <div id="image_src" align="center">
 <img src="Doc_image.jpg" align="middle" />
 </div>
</div>
<div id="right_panel">
<p><strong>
xxx</strong>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="left_footer">
<div id="img_left">
<img src="separator_bar.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>Help Topics &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<br />
<div id="left_list">
<ul >
<li>General Information</li>
<li>Getting Started</li>
<li>Functions</li>
<li>Additional Features</li>
</ul>
<br />
</div>
</div>
<div id="right_footer">
<div id="img_right">
<img src="separator_bar.jpg" />
</div>
<div>Manuals &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<br />
<div id="right_list">
<ul>
<li>Guide</li>
<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User Guide</li>
</ul>
<br />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 div {
    background-color:#ebeff5;
}

#image_header{
    background-color:#FFF
}

#header,#footer {
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;


    }

#left_panel,#left_footer{
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center

    }

#right_panel,#right_footer{
    width:250px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center

}

#left_panel h2{
    color:#002e5c;
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

#right_panel p {
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    padding:0px 10px;
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#002e5c
}

#left_list ul,#right_list ul{
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;


}

#left_list ul li,#right_list ul li{

    background-image:url(web%20bullet.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:55px 5px; 
    padding-left:15px;


}
```

Please suggest
Image attached
 ![image: List item]

Comment: There is a "vertical-align: middle;" CSS property, but I've only ever used them for `<td>`s and the like, so don't count on it working here, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: you mean horizontally aligned, right? you want them to all be in line with the bullets, not indented from the left like they are now?

Comment: @NathanWallace : Yes exactly !

Comment: O.O Please reword your question. :)

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vertical?s=t unfortunately the definition itself contains words difficult than _vertical_ :D

Comment: Are there other CSS style declarations not shown here that may also be affecting these list items?

Comment: Well, there are always an element's default values, if that's what you mean...

Comment: Hm, a demo of the provided code doesn't look like the provided image:  http://tinker.io/d8b39

Comment: it's working fine as expected http://jsfiddle.net/stw4j/1/. I have just change the background-position

Comment: try `ul{list-style-position:inside;}` - if not, inspect using firefox or chrome and see which other styles are affecting the `<li>`s

Comment: I have updated question with my complete code and css . I tried all the options suggested by you guys but still not getting the desired result ! Help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

From the image you uploaded it seems your looking for this:

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XE89x/7/)

```
<div id="left_list">
    <ul>
        <li>General Information</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Getting Started</li>
            <ul>
                <li>VIWeb Functions</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <li>Additional Features</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: from the image he put, its what he wants.

Comment: No , i don't want them to be indented . Right now text is not starting from the same position !I want text to be started from same position and it should be aligned properly!

Comment: Image showing his problems not the expected result as you can see in title

Comment: @abhinavsingh I have posted a comment above with JSFiddle.can you look into that and let us know if anything else is required

Answer (score 0):

I added `text-align:left` to both the `ul` and `li`

```
#left_list ul,#right_list ul{

    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-align: left;

}

#left_list ul li,#right_list ul li{
    background-image:url(web%20bullet.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:55px 5px; 
    padding-left:15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: He wants `text-align:center`. You can see from the image.

Comment: comments in below question say the the image is what he DOSNT WANT. OP please clarify?

Comment: And i have also added fixed `width` to his `div` so that he can check that it is horizontally centered within that `div`.

Comment: My  bad then :D

horizontally aligned can be left, center, right.

Comment: @abhinavsingh send me a link to your jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

fix to:

```
background-position:0px 5px; 
padding-left:20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

[In JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9SRp/)

```
        <body>
<div id="image_header">
<img src="header.jpg" width="500" height="54" />
</div>
<div id="header">
<div id="left_panel">
<h2 id="heading" align="cente">Welcome to the <br />
Help Center</h2>

 <div id="image_src" align="center">
 <img src="Doc_image.jpg" align="middle" />
 </div>
</div>
<div id="right_panel">
<p><strong>
xxx</strong>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="left_footer">
<div id="img_left">
<img src="separator_bar.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>Help Topics &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<br />
<div id="left_list">
<ul >
<li>General Information</li>
<li>Getting Started</li>
<li>Functions</li>
<li>Additional Features</li>
</ul>
<br />
</div>
</div>
<div id="right_footer">
<div id="img_right">
<img src="separator_bar.jpg" />
</div>
<div>Manuals &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<br />
<div id="right_list">
<ul>
<li>Guide</li>
<li>User Guide</li>
</ul>
<br />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
 div {
    background-color:#ebeff5;
}

#image_header{
    background-color:#FFF
}

#header,#footer {
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;


    }

#left_panel,#left_footer{
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center

    }

#right_panel,#right_footer{
    width:250px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center

}

#left_panel h2{
    color:#002e5c;
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

#right_panel p {
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    padding:0px 10px;
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#002e5c
}

#left_list ul,#right_list ul{
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;


}

#left_list ul li,#right_list ul li{

    background-image:url(http://katewhittington.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bulletpoint.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 5px; 
    padding-left:15px;
    text-align:left;


}

#left_list{margin-left:78px;}
#right_list{margin-left:68px;}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure @Cairnarvon. Updated.